# Bash script to enclose words in single quotes

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to enclose words contained in a file with single quotes.

> Word - Hello089
>
> Result - 'Hello089',

I tried the following regex but it doesn't work. This works in Notepad++ with find and replace. I'm not sure how to tweak it to make it work in bash scripting.

```
sed "s/(.+)/'$1',/g" file.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacement backreferences (also called placeholders) are defined with `\n` syntax, not `$n` (this is perl-like backreference syntax).

Note you do not need groups here, though, since you want to wrap the *whole lines* with single quotation marks. This is also why you do not need the `g` flags, they are only necessary when you plan to find multiple matches *on the same line*, input string.

You can use the following POSIX BRE and ERE (the one with `-E`) solutions:

```sh
sed "s/..*/'&',/" file.txt > result.txt
sed  -E "s/.+/'&',/" file.txt > result.txt
```

In the POSIX BRE (first) solution, `..*` matches any char and then any 0 or more chars (thus emulating `.+` common PCRE pattern). The POSIX ERE (second) solution uses `.+` pattern to do the same. The `&` in the right-hand side is used to insert the whole match (aka `\0`). Certainly, you may enclose the whole match with capturing parentheses and then use `\1`, but that is redundant:

```sh
sed "s/\(..*\)/'\1',/" file.txt > result.txt
sed  -E "s/(.+)/'\1',/" file.txt > result.txt
```

See the escaping, capturing parentheses in POSIX BRE must be escaped.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/kG6aHW).

```sh
s="Hello089";
sed "s/..*/'&',/" <<< "$s"
# => 'Hello089',
sed -E "s/.+/'&',/" <<< "$s"
# => 'Hello089',
```

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is expanded by the shell before `sed` sees it, but it's the wrong back reference anyway. You need `\1`. You also need to escape the parentheses that define the capture group. Because the `sed` script is enclosed in double quotes, you'll need to escape all the backslashes.

```
$ echo "Hello089" | sed "s/\\(.*\\)/'\1',/g"
'Hello089',
```

(I don't recall if there is a way to specify single quotes using an ASCII code instead of a literal `'`, which would allow you to use single quotes around the script.)